# Angular firebase: does not ask which features I want to add

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

In many Angular firebase tutorials, they always say I should enter this line in the terminal

`ng add @angular/fire`.

This then ONLY asks me for which project and will then never ask me which features I want to add (authentication, storage, ...)

[image]

Because of this, I am unable to import those functionality as well. How can I make it ask me? I have gotten the prompt in the past. Don't know why it stopped now.

FYI yes there is a web-project in the firebase project.

Comment: Yeah i have same problem. Why when i use `ng add @angular/fire` command it won't create ready to use requests to database i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firebase projects:list` to list your projects and `firebase use` to switch between projects.

Here's more in the doc for Firecbase CLI: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/